Allowing multiple user inputs
I'm very new to programming so I'm sure my code isn't as neat as possible, and I'm certain it isn't working how I would like it to. Basically, I'm playing around with this code, and I want to make it so that the user could input various synonyms to 'Yes' for the code to work properly (I have commented out the various options) but I can't seem to work out how to do it. Does anyone have any advice?
price = input('How much is a burger? ')

within_budget = float(price) <= 10.00
 
veggie = input('Is there a vegetarian option?')

is_veggie = veggie == 'Yes' #'Y', 'Definitely', 'yes', 'y', 'sure'

is_good_choice = within_budget and is_veggie

if is_good_choice:
  
print('This restaurant is a good choice')

if not is_good_choice:

  print('The restaurant is not a good choice')

I tried making a list but as I figured out, that then requires you to put in the whole list to return True, not just one string in the list.
It seems like a .lower function might be of some use and I've played around with it but I keep getting an error so I must be putting it in the wrong place.

veggie.lower() in  ['yes', 'y', 'definitely', 'yes', 'y', 'sure']

Try to improve your code format.  There's a syntax error (the statement after the first if needs to be indented).  And don't just mechanically double-space the entire thing.  It makes it needlessly difficult to read.  Instead, put your statements into logical groups.  Also, don't post code you haven't run.  Post your real code, not a buggy approximation to it.

@sahasrara62 People normally use a tuple for this, not a list.  There's no need for it to be mutable.

@TomKarzes yes, tuple is better than list  , this is just an example
